# storeXpathCount within an frame, Selenium IDE

Tags: iframe, xpath, selenium-ide

I want to store the count of li elements in an ul list. The list resides in an frame with the id `content frame`. I the li elements all contains an anchor tag with class `listHead`

First i tried this:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeXpathCount</td>
    <td>//ul/li/a[@class=listHead]</td>
    <td>countMax</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${countMax}</td>
    <td>${countMax}</td>
</tr>
```

The countMax returned is 0. If i change the target to `//*` i get an xpathCount of only 13. Inspecting the source showed that most of the page is within iframes. So, i tried adding select frame:

```
<tr>
    <td>selectFrame</td>
    <td>contentFrame</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeXpathCount</td>
    <td>//ul/li/a[@class=listHead]</td>
    <td>countMax</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${countMax}</td>
    <td>${countMax}</td>
</tr>
```

The echo of countMax still returns 0, and if changed to `//*` 13. How do I get a count of the elements in the frame? I am using Selenium IDE 2.5.0 w. firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your xpath attribute filter is missing quotes around the class name. Try:

```
//ul/li/a[@class="listHead"]
```

Comment: Good spot, however the main issue above my lack of ability to write properly was that while I was executing my rows using the keyboard shortcut x. My selectFrame got lost between the execution of rows... running the full test worked with your "" fix